# In LoopBack, can I reuse LDAP groups as Roles for my users?

Tags: ldap, acl, loopbackjs, role

Via Passport's plugins I am able to connect my LDAP databases to LoopBack for authentication purposes.

In my current setup, I have a set of groups in LDAP that creates authorization for other services. For example, I have a `chat` group, which define which user can use our internal chat server.

My goal here is to reduce the redefinition of groups. I would like to only have one place where every group/role are defined, so for that I would like to match all my LDAP's group as Roles in LoopBack.

Is there a way to map those groups as Roles for LoopBack? And if so, is there an example of such behaviour/configuration somewhere online?

Ideally, I would be able to do the same for ACLs, as I can also store those in the LDAP databases.